# Error handling middleware thenables nodejs express

Tags: express, mongoose, error-handling, middleware

So I have this error handler middleware

```
class ErrorHandler extends Error {
    constructor(statusCode, message) {
        super();
        this.statusCode = statusCode;
        this.message = message;
    }
}

const handleError = (err, res) => {
    const { statusCode, message } = err;
        res.status(statusCode).json({
            status: "error",
            statusCode,
            message: "resource not found"
        });
};

module.exports = {
    ErrorHandler,
    handleError
}
```

calling it in index.js

```
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    handleError(err, res);
})
```

And I want to use it in all my methods, but I cant figure it out how to use it with catch. it does not seem very clear for me. For the 404 error works just fine, but If I'm trying to throw a 500 error, e.g. a ReferenceError I dont know how to use my function.

```
exports.getAll = function(req, res, next) {
    User.find({})
        .exec()
        .then(users => {
            if (users.length === 0) {
                throw new ErrorHandler(404, "No users found");
            } else {
                res.json(users);
                next;
            }
         })
        .catch(error => {
            res.status(500).send({
                message: "Error finding users",
                error: error
            })
        })
};
```

in .catch I want to use my error handler like I did in .then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in catch block, you can use next to go handle error like with `next(err)`

```
.catch(err=>{
  let error = new ErrorHandler(500,"Error finding users");
  next(error);
})
```

Comment: i forgot tu change that if, it wasnt working anyway. I tried your approach before, in catch block but it doesn't work

Comment: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: No users found it gives this error at that line

Comment: @ValentinaBarna you can check out this link for error handling https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html.I had replaced catch block with approach as mentioned in the above link. Do check it out.

Comment: I think i've fixed it for now. added let error =  new ErrorHandler(404, "No users found");
next(error); in if block. thanks